# Word wrap text field in Xcode 6

Tags: textfield, xcode6, word-wrap

I'm trying to word wrap/wrap text the paragraph I added as a non-editable text field in Xcode 6. I have 'Line Breaking' set to 'Word Wrap' already, but it's still cutting off the text after one line. Is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Figured out text fields can only be 1 line, so created it as a label instead, set lines attribute to 0, then dragged to size object and word wrap appropriately.